# Getting Error About Arrays Must Be the Same Length

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, k-means

I'm pulling data from a CSV into a DF, and running the code below....getting this error:

```
# Import the necessary packages
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
# Define a normalizer
normalizer = Normalizer()

# Fit and transform
norm_movements = normalizer.fit_transform(dfMod) 


# Create Kmeans model
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 10,max_iter = 1000)
# Make a pipeline chaining normalizer and kmeans
pipeline = make_pipeline(normalizer,kmeans)
# Fit pipeline to daily stock movements
pipeline.fit(dfMod)
labels = pipeline.predict(dfMod)


print(len(labels), len(dfMod)) 


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'labels':labels,'dfMod':list(dfMod)}).sort_values(by=['labels'],axis = 0)


# now...with PCA reduction
# Define a normalizer
normalizer = Normalizer()
# Reduce the data
reduced_data = PCA(n_components = 2)
# Create Kmeans model
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 10,max_iter = 1000)
# Make a pipeline chaining normalizer, pca and kmeans
pipeline = make_pipeline(normalizer,reduced_data,kmeans)
# Fit pipeline to daily stock movements
pipeline.fit(dfMod)
# Prediction
labels = pipeline.predict(dfMod)
# Create dataframe to store companies and predicted labels
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'labels':labels,'dfMod':list(dfMod.keys())}).sort_values(by=['labels'],axis = 0)
```

This line throws the error.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'labels':labels,'dfMod':list(dfMod)}).sort_values(by=['labels'],axis = 0)
```

The weird thing is, that this shows 50k and 50k.

```
print(len(labels), len(dfMod)) 
50000 50000
```

Am I missing something here?   How can I make this work?  Thanks!!

Comment: Can you share exactly what the error is?

Comment: Can you print `labels.size`, `dfMod.size`?

Comment: Have you looked at the shape of each? One might have an extra dimension. Also, if dfMod is a dataframe, you can use dfMod.values or dfMod.values.tolist()

Comment: That worked Mark.  Thanks!!